# How To Get Reflections On A Smooth Surface?

Tags: hdri, reflection, roughness

I have downloaded a blend file from the internet. In that, on a smooth surface, a house image is reflected. but no house is in the environment. How to do this?

See this image:

[image]

<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a preview mode known as "material preview". This mode uses a hidden HDRI image to provide reflections and lighting. If you look at the top right of the 3D viewport, you will see there are 4 little circles - these are the preview modes (from left to right - *wireframe, solid, material, rendered*). You have the second from the right selected (material preview).

Pick the one on the very right (rendered preview) to see your object with your own lighting setup. You can also press <kbd>Z</kbd> in the viewport and select *rendered* from the pie menu that appears.

[image: Reflect]

If you want to see the image, click on the arrow on the right and increase the World Opacity from the menu.

If you want to set up your own image so the reflection shows but the image doesn't, in your World Shader, combine your image (Environment Texture) with a Background node with the color of your choice by mixing them with a Mix Shader, using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a Light Path node as the Mix Factor:

[image: Reflect2]

Comment: just another possibility is to add a very big sphere (that everything of your scene fits in) so you will not see the hdri itself, but just the "inside" of the sphere, but you will get the lighting and the reflections of your hdri. hopefully there are nod disadvantages of this...but i am not sure, i am pretty new to blender too

Comment: this is an excellent explanation. very detailed. thanks bro.